# Azure DevOps Pipelines stopped running

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to deploy a new project through Azure DevOpsPipelines and it shows is as queued for an hour (normally it starts right away or within minutes).

It also says "This agent request is not running because you have reached the maximum number of requests that can run for parallelism type 'Microsoft-Hosted Private'. Current position in queue: 1"

I have also tried to run a pipeline for one of my existing projects and it has the same issue. Last time I successfully deployed for this projects 8 days ago.

I have seen that they have introduced new rules for free grants for Azure Pipelines for new organizations. I was wondering if these rules are applied to all organizations (including old ones)?

I have sent the email as they requested I am just wondering if they have just taken the free access to Azure pipelines from everyone?

I am also quite new to Azure DevOps so I am wondering if this is a regular thing that Azure services just stop working?

thanks everyone!

Update:
[here is my parallel jobs screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlxP8.png)

Update:
[my Azure Pipelines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uc8gK.png)

Comment: Those changes are only for new organizations: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/change-in-azure-pipelines-grant-for-private-projects/
Please check yours quotas in project settings -> Parallel jobs

Comment: @BartoszPelikan thank you, I have added the screenshot of my "parallel jobs" page. I am not sure where the quotas there. Would you please help?

Comment: @python84 According to your screenshot of parallel jobs page, there is no free grant in your organization yet. If you have already sent the email, please be patient for a few days. If you did not send an email, please refer to this [release note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/sprint-184-update#azure-pipelines-1) and send the email.

Comment: @WalterQian-MSFT , thank you! it means that they have taken the free access for me. Because before it was running well.

Comment: According to the note in the [release note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/sprint-184-update#azure-pipelines-1):This change only impacts new organizations. It doesn't apply to existing projects or organizations. This does not change the amount of free grant you can get. It only adds an extra step to get that free grant. Anyway, if you have sent the email, they will respond within a few days.

Comment: @WalterQian-MSFT , thank you! it means that they have taken the free access from my organization. Because before it was running well. I know exactly WHY they do it I was just not aware they are taking the free access from existing organizations. I have ran the pipelines before for this organization successfully and that's why I didn't think this was the issue.

Comment: Did you also use Microsoft-hosted agent before? If you used self-hosted agents, it is as expected. Please check your history of your pipeline, you can find your origin configuration there.

Comment: @WalterQian-MSFT I was using Microsoft-hosted agent, I didn't change anything from last time I ran the pipeline. I have attached a picture of the history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering if these rules are applied to all organizations
> (including old ones)?

This change only impacts new organizations. It doesn't apply to existing projects or organizations. This does not change the amount of free grant you can get. It only adds an extra step to get that free grant.

> I have sent the email as they requested I am just wondering if they
> have just taken the free access to Azure pipelines from everyone?

It may take some days to process your requests, please wait patiently.

> I am wondering if this is a regular thing that Azure services just
> stop working?

Azure Pipelines has been offering free CI/CD to public and private projects for several years. Because this amounts to giving away free compute, it has always been a target for abuse – especially crypto mining. Minimizing this abuse has always taken energy from the team. Over the past few months, the situation has gotten substantially worse, with a high percentage of new projects in Azure DevOps being used for crypto mining and other activities we classify as abusive. Several service incidents over the past month have been caused by this abuse resulting in long wait times for existing customers.

To address this situation, we've added an extra step for new organizations in Azure DevOps to get their free grant.

Please refer to this [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/sprint-184-update#azure-pipelines-1).

As a temporary alternative, you can install and use self-hosted agents. Please refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops).

Comment: Thank you! they have given me my free access back after I sent them an email. It took them around 48 hours to process.